# jquery cascade dropdownlist will clear after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have made a cascade dropdown list using jquery and ajax, the first dropdown shows states and the second one shows cities according to selected state.
when a postback occurs I can get selected city with this code:

```
Request.Form[DpCity.UniqueID];
```

but the city list will clear. how can I retain the city list values during postback something like using view state?

Comment: You need to re-initialize the list after the postback, using the DpCity.UniqueID

Comment: But it requires to connect to database again and I think it's not such a good idea.

Comment: I have the same, issue, did you fix it?

Comment: I reinitialize the dropdown list.